# Reinforcement Learning (Q Learning)

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I was reading a paper on **traffic flow optimization** using Multi-Agent Q learning. the paper proposes the following method:
Deploy a Reinforcement learning controller at each intersection with traffic lights.

first the Q value equation is:

$Q^{t}(s,a) = (1- \alpha )Q^{t-1}(s,a) +  \alpha (R{t} +  \gamma max_{a}(Q^{t-1}(s,a))$

second the state is:
the sum of vehicle queues lengths at the current intersection and one hop intersections

third the action space is:

[image: the action space]

here the actions represent the possible moves of vehicles at the intersection.

forth the reward at time t is

$R^{t} = -( w_1\sum q_{current intersection} + w_2\sum q_{neighbors} )$

where the q refers to vehicle queues lengths, w1 and w2 are constants.

fifth there is the algorithm in the image below where it acquires the action required for maximizing the Q value

[image: Algorithm]

What I am trying to understand is, the reward calculation does not take an action as a parameter. How does it choose an action properly.

I am a newbie to reinforcement learning, so please if you find my question naive, cosedire referring me to a proper textbook.
Thanks

Comment: This shows little effort in trying to make a proper question. First, as suggested by @NeilSlater, consider inserting the equations properly in the text and also provide background, state what you have understood so far and what exact information do you need in the potential answers. I can probably help you clarifying some concepts if I properly understand what are you trying to ask here.

Comment: I am sorry i'm just a newbie here and the way I proposed my question may not be practical.
This is a method for action selection I am aware of that.
I will edit the question to make it better.

Comment: @AdnanSaood Pls cite the paper.

Comment: @horaceT 
Liu, Y., Liu, L., & Chen, W. P. (2017). Intelligent Traffic Light Control Using Distributed Multi-agent Q Learning. arXiv preprint arXiv:1711.10941.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying to understand is, the reward calculation does not take an action as a parameter. How does it choose an action properly.

The reward function does not choose the action. It gives the immediate *consequences* for your previous action - and in most cases is a consequence of all previous actions, states and random factors in the environment. Although it should only *depend* on most recent state, previous action plus a random factor at most.

In your case reward depends directly on the resulting state = how many cars at each junction after taking an action, and not *directly* on the previous action = which traffic flow to enable. It does still depend on the action indirectly, via however the environment works. But that does not need to be expressed mathematically (as a model of the system) for Q learning to work. Although not stated, the reward probably also depends on a random factor outside of your control = how many cars turn up at each junction.

It is the Q value which eventually ranks the different actions and allows you to select the best action. The value $Q^t(s, a)$ gives you the current best estimate for future rewards (for a continuous problem, such as yours, it is common to have a discount factor, $\gamma$, to give more weight to immediate rewards).

There are multiple ways to select the next action in reinforcement learning, depending on the problem, your learning algorithm etc. In the example pseudo-code you copied, the selection process is using [Upper Confidence Bound](http://banditalgs.com/2016/09/18/the-upper-confidence-bound-algorithm/) (or UCB), which is a relatively sophisticated way of balancing exploration of actions that *might* be better than your current best estimate, versus simply using the "best" action so far. If you always took the "best" action, in many cases this would cause a problem because you would never update your knowledge of what the other actions do.

One of the standard textbooks for all this is [Sutton & Barto, *Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction*](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html). The notation in that book is slightly different to what you have used, but it explains the concepts involved in your problem in easy-to-understand detail.